# Missing level of technical depth (Recursive to Iterative)

Tags: java, interview-questions, iteration

I recently have given a coding test in a reputable IT company. There were three coding questions.

They refused me by saying that

> as we felt they didn't demonstrate the level of technical depth we're
>   seeking from candidates

Please help me understanding what type of the technical depth my solution is missing? Thanks

**Question 2 :** [Missing level of technical depth (Flatten Tree)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51545/java-interview-missing-level-of-technical-depth-flatten-tree)

**Question 3 :** [Missing level of technical depth (Common Ancestor)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51547/java-interview-missing-level-of-technical-depth-common-ancestor)

and this is the **1st question**.

**Question 1:**

> Reimplement this code so that its results will always be the same, but
>   that it does not cause a stack overflow on large inputs.  Your
>   solution must still implement the Folder interface.

**Answer 1:**

```
package iteration;

import java.util.Queue;

public interface Folder<T, U>
{
    U fold(U u, Queue<T> list, Function2<T,U,U> function);
}
```

---

```
package iteration;

public interface Function2<T, U, R>
{
  R apply(T t, U u);
}
```

---

```
package iteration;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

public class MyFolder<T, U> implements Folder<T, U>
{


     public U fold(U u, Queue<T> ts, Function2<T, U, U> fun) {

        if(u == null || ts == null || fun == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        if (ts.isEmpty()) {
            return u;
        }

      //get an iterator first instead of forEach loop, because poll() is modifying underlying collection/queue
        Iterator<T> iter = ts.iterator(); 
        while (iter.hasNext()) { //loop over the items

            u = fun.apply( ts.poll() , u); 

        } 

        return u;
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Folder<Integer,Integer> folder = new MyFolder<Integer, Integer>();

        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        for(int lop =0; lop < 1000000; lop++ ){ //add some values in the Queue
            q.add(lop);
        }
        Integer result = folder.fold(0, q, new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
            public Integer apply(Integer val1, Integer val2) {
                return val1 + val2;
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context on the task? Was it related to any real system or just imaginary? And what did the original code look like?

Comment: This code was given to me and was told to just make it iterative. It was previously recursive. Besides I wasn't given any context nor other details.

Comment: The question says *reimplement*, what is the original code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> as we felt they didn't demonstrate the level of technical depth we're seeking from candidates

This is a stock response. The engineers who interviewed you probably said something like “nah, not good enough”, so someone in HR sent you their stock response. Don't worry about the exact words; it wasn't written about you.

Some problems they might have objected to:

- `fold` shouldn't throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when `U` is `null`; `null` is a reasonable input.
- It traverses the `Queue` with both `Queue.poll` (which removes the first element) *and* an iterator (which doesn't modify the queue). Pick one or the other. Doing both may not even have well-defined behavior — what happens to the iterator when you remove the current element?
- The initial `isEmpty` check is redundant. If the queue is empty, the iteration loop will do nothing.
- There are lots of blank lines that take space without contributing to readability. That you include them in such a small program suggests you're not used to large programs.

There are also some design flaws in the specification.

- `Folder` should not be an interface. It makes no sense to create an object in order to call its `fold` method; `fold` should simply be a static method.
- If the original version used `Queue.poll` instead of an iterator, then it destroys the contents of the queue. It's usually not a good idea to modify arguments unnecessarily, because it tends to create bugs.
- `fold` should probably accept any `Iterable`, not just a `Queue`.

If you *didn't* point out these problems, they might take that as a sign you wouldn't notice design flaws in real work either. Part of a programmer's job is noticing problems and (when feasible) fixing them!

Comment: Generally I agree, but Folder as an interface with one method does make sense. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: @Tom: Reifying a strategy is useful only to allow switching between multiple strategies, but there's no indication that's needed here.

Comment: In an interview setting, there's rarely an indication of why complexity is needed. Here, it could be as simple as including an interface to see how comfortable an applicant is with implementing an interface.